# Does anyone have any suggestions on how to make a searchable frequently asked questions document?

Tags: python, database, user-interface, search, searchbar

**I have created a word document with questions paired up with answers**, and general topics paired up with relevant information.

**I would like to create a searchable version of the document**, where you can search words/phrases/keywords and view the relevant answers and topics. Some of the answers/topics have pictures associated with them. Links between answers/topics would also be helpful.

It looks like you can achieve what I would like in SharePoint: https://sharepointmaven.com/3-ways-create-faq-knowledge-base-sharepoint/

However, I am not keen on paying for a subscription for a document that will only be used by a few people.

**Does anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve this?**

I have a some coding experience. I was thinking of making an application in Python with a GUI that has a search bar, searches a database and displays relevant information. Would welcome any advice, recommended guides or alternative products to SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [docker](https://www.docker.com/get-started) to set up some form of relational database such as [postgres](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres).

From there you could make a table in the database for your questions and answers from your word document.

I'd recommend using the [psycopg2](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/) python module to access your database.

For a desktop application,  I'd recommend looking at [Tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tk.html) for a nice GUI and packaging it with [pyinstaller](https://pypi.org/project/pyinstaller/).

I hope this gives you some ideas of how to move forward with this.

Comment: Thank you, I will try just that.

For my own future reference, here is a guide on an autocompleting search bar in Tkinter: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tkinter-discuss/2012-January/003041.html